# using android phone as a bluetooth keyboard for another android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'd like to use my old android phone as a bluetooth keyboard for my new android phone. There seems to be plenty of solutions when it comes to using the phone as a keyboard for windows, but no solutions for android->android connection. How would I go about implementing one?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can do that via a simple Bluetooth pairing as you wish to do. But did you tried the Android App store? There are multiple Apps (which can be installed on both devices) for example "[Tablet Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tournesol.tabletremote)" which description said "Tablet Remote let you control an Android tablet or phone with another Android device".